# Mysql printing First N line of result

Tags: mysql

I have this table :

```
Orders(Orderid,CustomerID,Amount)
```

I ask id's of **top 10** customers (total amount of order)

I wrote the query which is print all customer (highest amount to min amount)

```
select CustomerID, sum(Amount) as Total from orders group by CustomerID order by Total desc;
```

How can I get the first 10 line of this result ? Or  is my way to obtain top 10 wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
select CustomerID, sum(Amount) as Total
from orders 
group by CustomerID
order by Total desc
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works. I even don't know that there is a limit parameter in mysql :/